# jquery/json access data outside getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

How do I get access to json data outside `$.getJSON`, is it even possible? if not, how to do this other way?

```
var json = [];
$.getJSON("test.json", function(data) {
   json = data;
});

// Here I want to display data from json
console.log(json["en"].name);
```

test.json

```
{
    "en": {
        "name": "John"
    },
    "pl": {
        "name": "Jan"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
json= {};


//...


console.log(json.en.name);
```

a json is an object not an array

Comment: i guess the downvote was for the incomplete answer, sorry, updated !

Comment: Technically, it should be possible to do object[key] for member names. Its a common way to access members on json objects. Not an array, its a map underneath. Wondering if his question is related to scope, not syntax.

Comment: not if you declare your var as being of array type which he does in his question `[]!=={}` ; but probably true syntax issue although me would not do what you suggest except if the json is itself an object of array of object `{ [0] {},  ... }`